# Is it possible to change the url called by WAMP?

Tags: port, wamp

When click `1` and/or `2` WAMP open the web without my configured IP

i.e.

`1` open http://localhost/, I need localhost:8080
`2` open http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/, I need localhost:8080

Is it possible to add the port in WAMP's configuration somewhere? Currently I add it manually.

[image]

Thanks to `JK` suggestion I've try and found that in `wampmanager.tpl` file, search for `localhost` will expose the marked-red area which help to add the port.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Navigate to your WAMP installation folder and locate the files wampmanager.ini and wampmanager.tpl. Replace all occurrences of localhost with localhost:8080 within these two files. Restart wampserver.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, @JK, the wampmanager.tpl is the template file used (by wampmanager.exe during start up) to generate wampmanager.ini. So you only need to edit the .tpl file and that solves it.

*TIP: You can also add custom menus to your wamp tray icon by adding entries to the wampmanager.tpl file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `C:\wamp64\wampmanager.conf` and change the port:

```
[apache]
apachePortUsed = "8080"
```

Then exit and relaunch wamp.